# Is there any way to focus on a cell of a DataGrid without setting it to editable?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, accessibility

I am currently working on making my Flex application accessible.

I have an mx DataGrid that I am using for showing complex data. Each row contains information about a person and one of the columns contains a button to "submit" that person's information.

Currently if I tab to the DataGrid, it has focus on the whole thing, but I cannot tab to individual cells. For accessibility purposes, I need the user to be able to tab to each of these cells to read the information. Everywhere I've looked I've found that it seems the only way to focus on an individual cell is to set the editable property to true. However, I do not want to make the field editable, as that information should not be changed.

At the very least I would like to be able to tab to the cell that has the button ItemRendender for each person. I could set the rest of the information in the accessibilityName of that.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Or am I going to have to find a more "creative" solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering how to get around this, the only way I could find is to switch over to an AdvancedDataGrid. If you set the ADG's selectable property to true, you can use the arrow keys to select a whole row at a time, and the screen reader will read the whole row of information.

Then to get the effect of clicking the row's button, I set a keyboard event watcher that performs the function of the button using the target(ADG)'s selected item when you press space.

Comment: the selectionMode also includes "singleCell"